# Is there and R function for recoding variables?

Tags: r, spss

I’m making the leap from SPSS to R but having a few teething issues.

I’m trying to recode a variable but I’m getting error messages.

Here are some examples of the SPSS code I’m trying to translate:

```
RECODE income (1, 2 = 1) (3, 4 = 2) INTO income2.
EXECUTE.

* Recode to String.
STRING sex_values (A8).
RECODE sex (1 = 'Male') (2 = 'Female') INTO sex_values.
EXECUTE.
```

Comment: Take a look at the `factor` variable type. There are options for recoding factors in base r, and there is also a package `forcats` that provides a number of convenient functions for manipulating factors.

Answer (score 2):

Please take a look at a function funnily enough named as recode.

```
library(dplyr)
char_vec <- sample(c("a", "b", "c"), 10, replace = TRUE)
recode(char_vec, a = "Apple")
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a numeric vector containing numbers from the set 1, 2, 3, 4 and you want to replace 1 and 2 with "male" and 3 and 4 with "female" then here are some alternatives.

**1) factor**  This creates such a factor.  `as.character(income2)` can be used if you want a character vector instead.

```
income <- c(2, 1, 4, 3, 1, 4, 2)
income2 <- factor(income, levels = 1:4, labels = c("male", "male", "female", "female"))
income2
## [1] male   male   female female male   female male  
## Levels: male female
```

**2) subscripting** This creates a character vector

```
income2 <- c("male", "male", "female", "female")[income]
income2
## [1] "male"   "male"   "female" "female" "male"   "female" "male"
```

**3) car::recode** There is a `recode` function in the car package (and also a slightly different one in the dplyr package and likely others in other packages).  This creates a character vector. Add the `as.factor = TRUE` argument if you want the result to be a factor.

```
# assumes car package installed
income2 <- car::recode(income, "1:2='male';3:4='female'")
income2
## [1] "male"   "male"   "female" "female" "male"   "female" "male"
```

Comment: The only other capability i'd add is R's ability to pass a very SPSS-like list for recoding too: `income2 <- factor(income); levels(income2) <- list("male"=c(1,2), "female"=c(3,4))`

Answer (score 0):

As in many things in R, there are numerous ways to do this.

The first is to use the `ifelse` function. This is a useful function for reclassifying vectors as it evaluates in a way that conditions are met before replacement so, more complex statments are supported.

```
( x <- sample(1:2,20,replace=TRUE) )
  ifelse(x == 1, "male", ifelse(x == 2, "female", NA))
  ifelse(x == 1, "male", "female")
  ifelse(x == (1 | 2),"male","female")
```

You can also directly replace an element in the vector

```
x[x == 1] <- "male"
x[x == 2] <- "female"
print(x)
```

There is also using a factor and recoding using `levels`

```
( x <- as.factor(sample(1:2,20,replace=TRUE)) )
levels(x)[1] <- "male"
levels(x)[2] <- "female"
print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use the `if_else()` function to replace/recode your data in R for simplicity.

The `if_else(condition, true_result, false_result)` check if the condition is meet, it returns true_result, if not, returns the false_result instead.

For example `x= 3` and `if_else(x>2,"yes","no)` will return the output:

"yes"

---

So, in your case, you may use the following:

```
if_else(sex==1,"Male","Female")
if_else(income==(1 | 2),1,2)
```

In this case you can just put your data's `sex` column and `income` column in the above functions to recode them.

Comment: If by "default" you mean base R then `if_else` is not the "default" function. It is from `dplyr` package. `ifelse` is base R. Also are you sure `if_else(income==(1 | 2),1,2)` works as intended? Try with `income = 2`.